Topology of directed graph $G$ with non-singular adjacency matrix
Given a directed graph $G$ with non-singular adjacency matrix,

Q. Is there a directed
subgraph $H$ in $G$ that can be represented as the union of disjoint  cycles such that $H$ contains all nodes of $G$?


Do you want the cycles to be directed?

Yes, they are also directed sub-graph of $G$.

There is an edge emanating from any vertex of $G$ because otherwise the corresponding row (or column, according to our convention for forming the adjacency matrix) would be zero. Label the vertices as $v_1,\dots,v_n$. According to the observation just made, for any $i$, we can pick an index $f(i)$ such that there is a directed edge from $v_i$ to $v_{f(i)}$—thus a function
$f:\{1,\dots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,\dots,n\}$. There clearly exists an index $k$ and a positive integer $m$ such that $f^{\circ m}(k)=k$ and $k,f(k),\dots,f^{\circ (m-1)}(k)$ are pairwise distinct. Now $v_k,v_{f(k)},\dots,v_{f^{\circ (m-1)}(k)}$ is a directed cycle of $G$.
Update) The OP seems to be asking for a subgraph $H$ which is a disjoint union of directed cycles; and furthermore, contains all vertices of $G$. This harder question asks if every vertex of $G$ belong to a directed cycle. For this to hold, every vertex should belong to a directed cycle. My argument above shows that $G$ admits a directed cycle if no row of its adjacency matrix is zero. To show the stronger result that every vertex of $G$ belongs to a directed cycle, one should exploit the non-singularity of the adjacency matrix. Here is a simple argument based on the Cayley-Hamilton theorem: Denote the adjacency matrix by $A$—the entry $(i,j)$ is $1$ iff there is a directed edge from $v_i$ to $v_j$ ($i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$). By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, there is a linear combination of $n\times n$ matrices $I,A,\dots,A^{n-1}$ which is zero and has $\pm\det(A)\neq 0$ as the coefficient of $I$. Considering entries $(i,i)$ ($1\leq i\leq n$ arbitrary), we deduce that for at least one of the matrices $A,\dots,A^{n-1}$ the entry at that position is non-zero. But if the entry $(i,i)$ of the $m^{\rm{th}}$ power of the adjacency matrix, $A^m$, is non-zero, then $v_i$ must lie on a directed cycle of length at most $m$.
Update 2) I am adding my comments to the solution following OP's request. The solution is really Fedor Petrov's. My solutions above were only partial.

There exist disjoint directed cycles containing all vertices of $G$ if
and only if the adjacency matrix, $A$, has non-zero permanent (which
is of course the case if the adjacency matrix is non-singular).

Writing $A$ as $[a_{ij}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ where $a_{ij}$'s are non-negative integers, ${\rm{perm}}(A)\neq 0$ iff there exists a permutation $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $a_{1\sigma(1)}\dots a_{n\sigma(n)}\neq 0$. The cyclic decomposition of $\sigma$ then yields the desired disjoint cycles. Conversely, any collection of disjoint cycles of the graph $G$ involving all $n$ vertices amounts to a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for which $a_{1\sigma(1)}\dots a_{n\sigma(n)}\neq 0$.
Finally, the OP asked about the algorithmic aspect of this problem. I came across the following from the Theoretical CS Stack Exchange: cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/32887. By Valiant's theorem, the problem of computing the permanent for a binary matrix is #P-complete.  But the problem of deciding if ${\rm{perm}}(A)\neq 0$, or more generally, finding a permutation $\sigma$ with $a_{1\sigma(1)}\dots a_{n\sigma(n)}\neq 0$, has a polynomial-time solution because, as the link above outlines, it can be translated into the problem of finding a perfect matching in a bipartite graph.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a disjoint union of cycles containing all nodes of $g$. If so, how can we form other cycles?

@ABB The way your question reads, it says subgraph. Do you want the subgraph to include all vertices of $G$?

Firstly, thank you very much for your insightful arguments and amendments. However, I believe the procedure is not yet complete. Both algorithms indicate that for a given node, one can definitely find a cycle containing it. I'm struggling to understand how one can arrange the set of disjoint cycles so that all nodes can feasibly be included in one of them.

After finding the set of disjoint cycles containing all nodes of
$G$, the desired subgraph $H$ is formed by the union of these disjoint cycles.

Well, if $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ is the adjacency matrix, and it is non-singular, then its determinant (considered as a sum over permutations) has a non-zero term $\prod_i a_{i,\sigma(i)}$. It corresponds to a disjoint collection of cycles (these are cycles of the permutation $\sigma$ on $V$) which cover all vertices.

Great! Seems that your are addressing it by a known  theorem in a paper or some text. Could you please let me know the reference?

What do you mean? I refer to the definition of the determinant as a sum over permutations, nothing more

I mean that how can we explicitly address the algorithm leading us those disjoint  cycles  if the adjacency  matrix $A$ is given?

Any permutation corresponds to disjoint cycles. Another question is how do you find a permutation which has non-zero contribution to a determinant.

@ABB, as Fedor Petrov said, one needs to find a non-zero contributions. Indeed, you can replace determinant with permanent in your question: Such union of disjoint cycles exists iff the permanent of the adjacency matrix is non-zero. It follows easily from the definition as in Fedor's response.

Continued) For an algorithm to find such a union, a search in the CS Stack Exchange brings up this: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/32887. The problem of finding a permutation $\sigma$ with $a_{1\sigma(1)}\dots a_{n\sigma(n)}\neq 0$ can be translated into the problem of finding a perfect matching in a bipartite graph; this problem has polynomial time complexity ($a_ij$'s the entries of the adjacency matrix).   Once you have such a permutation $\sigma$, its cyclic decomposition provides you with the desired cycles.

@Khashf Your approach is now complete, it would be great if you add the recent comment in your answer below.
